# Whats the meaning of "redacted for privacy"

Tags: jframe

for some reason I have to check owner and information of a site .

I check this address
https://www.ghods-niroo.com
In
whois.icann.org

but the answer wonder me

who can explain

```
Contact Information
Registrant Contact

Name: REDACTED FOR PRIVACY
Organization: REDACTED FOR PRIVACY
Mailing Address: REDACTED FOR PRIVACY, REDACTED FOR PRIVACY REDACTED FOR PRIVACY REDACTED FOR PRIVACY REDACTED FOR PRIVACY
Phone: REDACTED FOR PRIVACY
Ext:
Fax: REDACTED FOR PRIVACYhttps://www.jetseo.ir/affiliate?refid=0f83e9
```

Comment: It means the information is hidden away because whoever that’s owning the domain didn’t want people to have access to that.

Comment: I know it , but how it possible to hide this information ?

Comment: The most european registrars hide this information for their customers in accordance to the GDPR.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understand it's because of the recent GDPR and ICANN policy changes.

https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/vbpgga/whois-gdpr-europe-icann-registrar

Comment: Tank you 
but link does not work

Comment: The Motherboard article is a bit outdated. The current situation is that ICANN - the organization managing domain names - has issues a temporary specification in May 2018 in order to be compliant with the new EU data protection laws (GDPR). Since then most details of the registrar are no longer publicly visible by WHOIS and instead shown as "redacted for privacy". See this article for details: http://domainincite.com/23007-icann-approves-messy-unfinished-whois-policy